# Web API Method Returns Result Set Even If Parameter Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've been playing around with routes and optional parameters and I'm stuck with a problem where no matter what I get a result from the database. Here's my method in my controller:

```
[Route("{companyID:int}/contact/{uid?}")]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable GetCompanyContactsByID(int companyID, Guid? uid = null)
{
    IQueryable<vwCompanyContact> contact = coreDB.vwCompanyContacts.Where(con => con.IDCompany == companyID);

        if (uid != null)
            contact = contact.Where(con => con.CatalogNumber == uid);

    return contact;
}
```

So basically if call (http://localhost:21598/DAL/api/company/100/contact/) I get a list of all the contacts of company 100.  And then if I call (http://localhost:21598/DAL/api/company/100/contact/64077706-b7c9-e411-825d-28b2bd14ba94666) I get just one record with the matching the GUID.  But then if I call (http://localhost:21598/DAL/api/company/100/contact/marryhadalittlelamb) I get the list of all the contact again.

I'd prefer to either receive an empty result set or a message back that says no results found.  I'm not sure how to approach this being that I'm still fairly new to C# and Linq.

**Here's the final code I ended up with:**

```
[Route("{companyID:int}/contact/{uid?}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetCompanyContactByID(int compantID, string uid = null)
{
    IQueryable<vwCompanyContact> contact 
        = coreDB.vwCompanyContacts.Where(con => con.IDCompany == companyID);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid))
    {
        Guid uidValue;
        if (Guid.TryParse(uid, out uidValue))
            contact = contact.Where(con => con.CatalogNumber == uidValue);
        else
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);;
    }

    return Ok(contact);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your parameter as `string` and reject the call if it can't be parsed to `Guid`:

```
[Route("{companyID:int}/contact/{uid?}")]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable GetCompanyContactsByID(int companyID, string uid = null)
{
    Guid? uidValue = null;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid) && !Guid.TryParse(uid, out uidValue))
         throw new ArgumentException("uid");

    IQueryable<vwCompanyContact> contact
        = coreDB.vwCompanyContacts.Where(con => con.IDCompany == companyID);

        if (uidValue.HasValue)
            contact = contact.Where(con => con.CatalogNumber == uidValue.Value);

    return contact;
}
```

Or you can have two separate overloads:

```
[Route("{companyID:int}/contact/")]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable GetCompanyContactsByID(int companyID)
{
    IQueryable<vwCompanyContact> contact
        = coreDB.vwCompanyContacts.Where(con => con.IDCompany == companyID);
    return contact;
}

[Route("{companyID:int}/contact/{uid}")]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable GetCompanyContactsByID(int companyID, Guid uid)
{
    IQueryable<vwCompanyContact> contact
        = coreDB.vwCompanyContacts.Where(con => con.IDCompany == companyID
                                                && con.CatalogNumber == uid);

    return contact;
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.. this helped alot - I'm going to update my question with the final code I ended up with

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyResponse
{
   public IList<vwCompanyContct> myContacts {set;get;}
   public string ResponseMessage {set;get;}
}

[Route("{companyID:int}/contact/{uid?}")]
[HttpGet]
public MyResponse GetCompanyContactsByID(int companyID, Guid? uid = null)
{
var response = new MyResponse();

    IQueryable<vwCompanyContact> contacts = 
coreDB.vwCompanyContacts.Where(con => (con.IDCompany == companyID) &&
                                      (uid == Guid.Empty || uid == CatalogNumber));

if(!contacts.Any()) response.ResponseMessage = "No Results found";
else
{
 response.ResponseMessage = String.Format("{0} contact is found", contacts.Count());
 response.MyContacts = contacts.ToList();
}

    return response ;
}
```